# Tests are not executed - JUnit 5 programatically + mvn exec

Tags: java, spring, maven-3, junit5

I'm working in a Selenium automation project to run regression tests. The tests are writen in JUnit 5.5.1. There is no Surefire or Failsafe plugins (tests aren't under src/test/java, they are located under src/main/java because are not unit tests).

The problem is when I run the code using the .bat file (that executes mvn exec:java ...), no one of tests are executed, and I'm not sure if my configuration is totally correct. In the worst case, it's a bug with the JUnit version that I'm using (I'm being using JUnit 5 since 1 week, so I'm unfamiliar with certain configurations yet). I'd appreciate so much the help of someone with more experience than me with JUnit 5.

This is what I get after to execute the .bat file. The .bat file contains something like:

```
mvn clean install exec:java -Dexec.args="'%some_env_as_arg_1%' '%some_env_as_arg_2%'" -DsomeExpectedEnv=%someExpectedEnv%

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -----------------< com.surecomp.doka:doka_automation >------------------
[INFO] Building doka_automation 1.0.1
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ doka_automation ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Automation\surecomp-automation-doka\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ doka_automation ---
[INFO] Using 'ISO-8859-1' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] Copying 13 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ doka_automation ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 13 source files to C:\Automation\surecomp-automation-doka\target\classes
[WARNING] No processor claimed any of these annotations: org.junit.jupiter.api.TestMethodOrder,org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired,org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource,org.junit.jupiter.api.Order,org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan,org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName,org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration,org.junit.jupiter.api.Test,org.springframework.stereotype.Component,org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInstance,org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith,org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.RegisterExtension,com.surecomp.automation.doka.testcases.IntegrationTest,org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration,javax.annotation.PostConstruct,org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy,org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean,org.junit.jupiter.api.Tag,org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy
[WARNING] /C:/Automation/surecomp-automation-doka/src/main/java/com/surecomp/automation/doka/exceptions/DOKAAutomationException.java:[8,8] serializable class com.surecomp.automation.doka.exceptions.DOKAAutomationException has no definition of serialVersionUID
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ doka_automation ---
[INFO] Using 'ISO-8859-1' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Automation\surecomp-automation-doka\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ doka_automation ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ doka_automation ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ doka_automation ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Automation\surecomp-automation-doka\target\doka_automation-1.0.1.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ doka_automation ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Automation\surecomp-automation-doka\target\doka_automation-1.0.1.jar to C:\Users\alvarot\.m2\repository\com\surecomp\doka\doka_automation\1.0.1\doka_automation-1.0.1.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\Automation\surecomp-automation-doka\pom.xml to C:\Users\alvarot\.m2\repository\com\surecomp\doka\doka_automation\1.0.1\doka_automation-1.0.1.pom
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) > validate @ doka_automation >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) < validate @ doka_automation <<<
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (default-cli) @ doka_automation ---
[27/08/2019 03:56:30.841] [ INFO] [TestsRunner.evaluateArgs:60] - -- evaluateArgs started --
[27/08/2019 03:56:30.854] [ INFO] [TestsRunner.evaluateArgs:65] - System propertie work.directory setted as: C:\Automation\Doka Work Directory
[27/08/2019 03:56:30.855] [ INFO] [TestsRunner.evaluateArgs:68] - System propertie selenium.driver.directory setted as: C:\Automation\surecomp-automation-config\drivers
[27/08/2019 03:56:30.856] [ INFO] [TestsRunner.evaluateArgs:69] - -- evaluateArgs finished --
[27/08/2019 03:56:30.859] [ INFO] [TestsRunner.readTestCasesFromCSVFile:97] - -- Reading of CSV file started --
[27/08/2019 03:56:30.860] [ INFO] [TestsRunner.readTestCasesFromCSVFile:98] - CSV file to read: C:\Automation\Doka Work Directory\cases.csv
[27/08/2019 03:56:30.862] [ INFO] [TestsRunner.readTestCasesFromCSVFile:120] - -- Reading of CSV file finished --
[27/08/2019 03:56:30.865] [ INFO] [TestsRunner.loadTestCases:84] - -- Test cases loading started --
[27/08/2019 03:56:31.599] [ INFO] [WebDriverUtils.getWebDriver:26] - Setting WebDriver as first time
Starting ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.68 (420c9498db8ce8fcd190a954d51297672c1515d5-refs/branch-heads/3809@{#864}) on port 38308
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
ago 27, 2019 3:56:35 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
[27/08/2019 03:56:35.498] [ INFO] [TestsRunner.loadTestCases:90] - Test case LoginITCase added to the test execution list.
[27/08/2019 03:56:35.506] [ INFO] [TestsRunner.loadTestCases:93] - -- Test cases loading finished --
[27/08/2019 03:56:35.514] [ INFO] [TestsRunner.runTestProgramaticallyInJUnit5:73] - -- Execution of test LoginITCase started --
[27/08/2019 03:56:36.089] [ INFO] [TestsRunner.runTestProgramaticallyInJUnit5:80] - -- Execution of test LoginITCase finished --

Test run finished after 332 ms
[         2 containers found      ]
[         0 containers skipped    ]
[         2 containers started    ]
[         0 containers aborted    ]
[         1 containers successful ]
[         1 containers failed     ]
[         2 tests found           ]
[         0 tests skipped         ]
[         0 tests started         ]
[         0 tests aborted         ]
[         0 tests successful      ]
[         0 tests failed          ]

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  10.925 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-08-27T03:56:36-03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Compilation process finished sucessful.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

This is my pom.xml config to get the JUnit Jupiter libs that I need:

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring.version>5.1.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <junit-platform.version>1.5.1</junit-platform.version>
        <junit-jupiter.version>5.5.1</junit-jupiter.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        ...

        <!-- Tests dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-platform.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        ...
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${automation-config-directory}</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.surecomp.automation.doka.TestsRunner</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
...
```

Executing tests programmatically with junit-plattform-launcher lib:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        evaluateArgs(args);
        String csvFilePath = SetupProps.getCsvFilename();
        //This will take each of test case defined in CSV file as an String array
        String[] testCasesIDs = readTestCasesFromCSVFile(csvFilePath);

        //For each one of the test cases ID finded, will be instantiate its own Test Case class
        loadTestCases(testCasesIDs);

        //Starts the execution of each test case
        SummaryGeneratingListener listener = new SummaryGeneratingListener();

        for (AbstractITCase testCase : testCasesList) {
            runTestProgramaticallyInJUnit5(listener, testCase);
        }
        TestExecutionSummary summary = listener.getSummary();
        summary.printTo(new PrintWriter(System.out));
    } catch (DOKAAutomationException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error catched. Process aborted.", e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Unexpected error catched in application. Process aborted.", e);
    }
}


private static void runTestProgramaticallyInJUnit5(SummaryGeneratingListener listener, AbstractITCase testCase) {
    LOGGER.info("-- Execution of test {} started --", testCase.getClass().getSimpleName());
    LauncherDiscoveryRequest request = LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request()
            .selectors(DiscoverySelectors.selectClass(testCase.getClass())).build();
    Launcher launcher = LauncherFactory.create();
    TestPlan testPlan = launcher.discover(request);
    launcher.registerTestExecutionListeners(listener);
    launcher.execute(request);
    LOGGER.info("-- Execution of test {} finished --", testCase.getClass().getSimpleName());
}
```

Super class for all test classes:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@IntegrationTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {AppConfig.class})
public abstract class AbstractITCase {
@RegisterExtension
protected static ReporterHandlerExtension runnerExtension = new ReporterHandlerExtension
        .Builder()
        .reports(extent)
        .driver(WebDriverUtils.getWebDriver())
        .build();

static {...}

@Autowired
protected WebDriver driver;
}
```

Login Test Class:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:test_values/login/login_ok_values.properties")
@DisplayName("Login Sucessful Scenario")
public class LoginITCase extends AbstractITCase {
    private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoginITCase.class);

    @Autowired
    LoginPage loginPage;

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Entering user and password")
    @Order(1)
    public void enterUsernameAndPassword() {
        LOGGER.info("-- enterUsernameAndPassword method started");
        driver.get(SetupProps.getDokaUrl());
        Assertions.assertTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(1), () -> {
            loginPage.enterUsernameAndPassword();
        });
        LOGGER.info("-- enterUsernameAndPassword method finished");
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Click button to login")
    @Order(2)
    public void clickButtonOkToLoggin() {
        LOGGER.info("-- clickButtonOkToLoggin method started");
        Assertions.assertTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(1), () -> {
            loginPage.clickButtonToLogin();
            loginPage.isLoginSucessful();
        });
        LOGGER.info("-- clickButtonOkToLoggin method finished");
    }
}
```

Interface to encapsulate test behavior (implemented by AbstractITCase class and inherited to all its childs:

```
@Component(value = "loginTest")
@Tag("IntegrationTest")
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE)
public @interface IntegrationTest {

}
```

Comment: I know it's off topic but why is it so complicated ? why don't you follow the standard ?

Comment: Because this artifact will be launched by non-programmers people, registering its own test codes for specific test cases through a CSV file. That test codes will be matched with a propertie file that have the Spring bean alias for every test case (not the class name because a class name may be changed in several times, causing errors with the app).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was an error raised internally by the Extension that I registered, nothing with the configuration on JUnit 5 neither Maven.

This Extension was created in order to handle ExtentReports API through test's lifecycle, creating report tests objects, logging results step by step and finally flushing the report to an HTML file.